# IIS 7.5 Windows Authentication Not Working in Chrome

Tags: webserver, authentication, intranet, iis-7.5, authorization

On a new installation of IIS 7.5 I have setup Windows Authentication on my Intranet.

The providers I have used are 'NTLM' and negotiate in that order.

This works fine in IE and Firefox but in chrome I get the following

> This web page is not available The web page at
>   http://mysite.com/myintranet.php might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web address. Error 338
>   (net::ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS): Unknown error.

I've tried looking online for a solution without any success.

I'm running the latest version of Chrome 21.0.1180.60

Comment: I would delete your cookies / temp files from Chrome and try again

Comment: I've tried this but it has had no effect.

Comment: I have a similar issue with IIS 8.5 and Chrome. All other browsers work fine. Chrome rejects the auth (logs show it doesn't pass a username). So if it's the same issue and you fixed it, I would like to know what you did.

Comment: Remove "negotiate" completely - don't just move it down the list.

It's and old question, I know, but I came up against this today, on an IIS server that was, until now, authenticating all browsers just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very well known and old issue. However, Shawn Weisfeld provided a year ago a solution [on his blog](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2011/08/02/iis-7-401.2-error.aspx):

> The fix was to force the web server to use NTLM. To do this in IIS 7 is just a setting in system.web/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/providers section of the web.config

Comment: FYI - the site doesn't work so it was a good thing you included the paragraph. I just used this solution for IIS 10 - it drove me nuts because the windows authentication worked in FireFox but not in Chrome. What is weird though is that I have a production server where Chrome doesn't seem to have an issue and it was not necessary to remove negotiate. I do not understand why it's working there.